# What is the MD5 sumcheck for elementryos-6.0-stable202111005? also elementryos-6.0-stable202111103?

Tags: install

What is the MD5 sumcheck for elementryos-6.0-stable202111005? also elementryos-6.0-stable202111103 ?

Answer (score 1):

they provide sha256 checksum for latest iso. can be seen here https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download